Finite variation in vectorial operations
If $\mathbf{a}=a_x\hat{\mathbf{x}}+a_y\hat{\mathbf{y}}$ and $ \mathbf{b}=b_x\hat{\mathbf{x}}+b_y\hat{\mathbf{y}}$ are two vectors, the scalar product is
$$\mathbf{a}\cdot \mathbf{b}=a_xb_x+a_yb_y$$
Using the derivates,
$$\frac{d \ (\mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{b} )}{dt} = \frac{d \ \mathbf{a}}{dt} \cdot \mathbf{b} + \mathbf{a} \cdot \frac{d \ \mathbf{b}}{dt} \tag 1$$
The same rule for the cross product between two vectors $\mathbf{a}, \mathbf{b}$:
$$\frac{d \ ( \mathbf{a} \times \mathbf{b} )}{dt} = \frac{d \ \mathbf{a}}{dt} \times \mathbf{b} + \mathbf{a} \times \frac{d \ \mathbf{b}}{dt} \tag 2$$
where the cross product is defined from:
$$\mathbf{a} \times \mathbf{b} = (a_yb_z-a_zb_y)\hat{\mathbf{x}} + (a_zb_x-a_xb_z)\hat{\mathbf{y}}+(a_xb_y-a_yb_x)\hat{\mathbf{z}}.$$
Additionally if $f(t)$ and $g(t)$ are two function, the operator $d$ and $\Delta$ are linear:
$$\frac{d(f\pm g)}{dt}=\frac{df}{dt}\pm \frac{dg}{dt}, \quad \frac{\Delta(f\pm g)}{\Delta t}=\frac{\Delta f}{\Delta t}\pm \frac{\Delta g}{\Delta t}$$
but for the product with the operator $d$
$$\frac{d(f\cdot g)}{dt}=\frac{df}{dt}\cdot g + f \cdot \frac{dg}{dt} \tag 3$$
it's true.

Is there also a similar operation with $Δ$ with the $(3)$? IMHO the answer is no.

My students of 16-year-old students do not know derivatives; and since I should proof how to obtain at the Coriolis acceleration, what needs to be done?"

One idea is to mimic the proof of the derivative of the product while keeping $\Delta$

You can always use finite varations instead of infinitesimal ones, provided you keep an $\varepsilon$ term and explain that it will be small regarding the other terms.
